# math operation in mysql returns same result for each row

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having a problem with this mysql query:

```
SELECT p.* , POW( [fixed_value1] - CAST(p.lat AS DECIMAL),2) + POW( [fixed_value2] - CAST(p.lon AS DECIMAL),2) as distance, l.type FROM [TABLE1] p
LEFT JOIN [TABLE2] l 
ON p.id = l.id 
AND l.uid = '4' 
WHERE [...  ...] ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 50
```

the result I get is everything fine, except for the decimal colum, it is always the same for each row.
I cannot find what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I recently deleted the CAST function and it works...

Comment: I was wondering about that. You might also want to square root the sum of the squares to get the distance.

Comment: Don't forget about the [MySQL spatial functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) before you go and write your own.

Comment: Bad implementation on the side of the engine but cast as decimal actually converts a number to a string and then fails to convert it back for doing the math.

Comment: @Mike I don't need the exact distance, I just wanted the result well ordered

Comment: @tadman I didn't realize about spatial functions, I'll take a look, thanks!